# Compiling NXP WiFi Driver on Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, wifi

I have a NXP Layerscape LS1012A development board (FRWY) running Layerscape, which is essentially just Ubuntu 20.04. I’ve plugged a PCIe WiFi module, Type 1XL by Murata (uses NXP WiFi chip 88W9098), into the PCIe slot on the dev board, and have obtained all the binary files needed to create a driver.

I’m having issues with the ‘make build’ command, and from what I’ve read it’s because I haven’t setup the Kernel correctly to make the build (I’m on kernel 5.10.35). Does anyone know how to properly set/build/prepare the kernel directory so this driver build can execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the first requirement for building kernel modules (drivers) is to have the build headers for the exact kernel version you are building the drivers for. Depending on distribution, these might be packaged as `kernel-headers-<kernel version number>` (Fedora/RHEL style) or `linux-headers-<kernel version number` (Debian/Ubuntu style). Some distributions might omit having a separate package for the headers, and will just require installing the complete kernel source package for building kernel modules (I think SuSE does this, or at least used to).

So, for a Ubuntu-like distribution, if you haven't done a `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, you should do that. You should also do a `apt-get install build-essential` to ensure you'll have the compiler and all the basic tools required.

One pitfall here is, if you have recently updated the system but not rebooted yet: the package manager will usually allow multiple kernel versions to co-exist, but usually keeps only the newest version of the build headers unless explicitly told to do otherwise. So the package manager might have installed an updated kernel that's waiting to be activated on next reboot, and also updated the build headers to match *that* kernel... which will stop you from building modules for your *current* kernel.

Usually, if you are using packaged kernels, and have installed the appropriate package containing the headers for your kernel version, there should be a symbolic link at `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build`, pointing at the directory the headers are located in. Often the third-party module/driver build process can use this to automatically find the build headers for your current kernel.

If you are building your own custom kernels, you can create such a symbolic link yourself: just point it at the root directory of the Linux source code tree you used to build your kernel in. For example:

```
ln -s /usr/local/src/linux-5.10.35 /lib/modules/5.10.35/build
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer thank you so much! I now have the driver built, but am unsure how to install it. Do you know how to install the built WiFi driver, or will I need to consult the specific driver’s README for steps?

Comment: The README would be the best option, but generally `make install` or perhaps `make modules_install` (just like when building the kernel itself) at the root of the driver source tree will usually install the driver module to the `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/`directory tree of the kernel version it was built for.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks! I’m very new here, so what do you mean by the root of the source tree? It looks like all the object files were created inside a folder named ‘bin_wlan,’ is that where I’d want to run the make install command?